# Android studio APP differences on virtual/real devices

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I'm running my app on a virtual device it runs fine but when I run it on my phone it looks like the app is too big for it.

In the lower part of `Gra : 1` is one button more.

Here is the image:

[image]

And here's how it looks in Android Studio:

[image]

Here is the `activity_main`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gracz 1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gracz 2"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/onescore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/one"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twoscore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/two"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/onescore"
        android:text="Zaczyna Gracz 1 [Krzyżyk]."
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:textSize="60sp"

        android:backgroundTint="#413f43"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/kto"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:textSize="60sp"

        android:backgroundTint="#413f43"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btn0"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/btn0"
       />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:textSize="60sp"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:backgroundTint="#413f43"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btn0"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/btn1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:textSize="60sp"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:backgroundTint="#413f43"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn0"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:textSize="60sp"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:backgroundTint="#413f43"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btn3"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt5"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:textSize="60sp"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:backgroundTint="#413f43"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btn4"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:textSize="60sp"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:backgroundTint="#413f43"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:textSize="60sp"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:backgroundTint="#413f43"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn4"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btn6"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:textSize="60sp"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:backgroundTint="#413f43"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn4"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btn7"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn8"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Gra : 1"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn8"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi. You don't show any layout files. Not sure how much help you'll get without those

Comment: I added it.....

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use absolute values for height and width for your buttons. Many devices have DIFFERENT resolutions. Some are really wide (like tablets) some are really narrow (like your real device). The virtual device you're using rather has a little bigger of a width. Now how to fix that ?

You should stop using absolute values like these:

```
 android:layout_width="135dp"
 android:layout_height="135dp"
```

Instead, if you want to be more adaptive with a larger spectrum of devices, you should start using "width percentage" (Since you have problems only in width). This is how it works:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3" />
```

This means, the width of the button will adapt to about 30% of your device's width. Make sure you change the layout_width to be ZERO. Afterthat, you can change the height programmatically to match your width if you want to make square buttons.

Also, for your lower button (below Gra : 1), try constraining it from below (`ConstraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"`) then start playing with the measurements of those big gray buttons so they can leave space for all the layout.

**EDIT**: Forgot to mention the reason why your layout surpasses the lower edge of the screen, that's because hierarchy of your constraints are technically "interweaving", in other words: you constraint something to something above it and so on, they are all ordered so when you don't have enough vertical space, the app follows your constraints only and keeps expanding the layout even if some of it is not visible. That's why it's **not** a good idea to use such constraints. Always try to use screen limits as your constraints.